# Why is BIRT formatting my Date/Time parameter in EDT time?

Tags: javascript, timestamp, birt

Trying to query a timestamp field in DB2.

Using 2 parameters for a between query.  Need to add 1 minute to the ending parameter.

Parameter format:  Custom: yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss
Parameter type:  date/time

Before open script:

```
var ToDate = params["rpToDate"].value;
var ToDate2 = BirtDateTime.addMinute( ToDate, 1 );
this.queryText=this.queryText.replaceAll("'BLHS'", ToDate2);
```

"BLHS" value comes out as `Mon Jan 01 00:01:00 EST 2024`

I need a timestamp format.

Answer (score 0):

Because you are using implicit type conversion to a string in the last line.

You should *never* rely on on the format of an implicit conversion.

In other words: Never use implicit type conversion except for trivial cases like converting between different number types or converting between int and string.

Converting between float and string depends on locale settings (eg. in German the meaning of dot and comma in numbers is exchanged in comparison to English).

Converting between date/time and string depends on locale settings, too.

**EDIT:** The text above answers the main question: BIRT formats a datetime value in a locale dependent way.
But the OP wants to know how to get a specific format.

You can convert a datetime value to a string in a specific format by using `Formatter.format(value, pattern)`,
e.g. to extract only the date (without time) in a typical German format, use

```
Formatter.format(dateValue, 'dd.MM.yyyy')
```

The capital `MM` for month, `mm` would be minutes.

**Recommendations**

1. Since you are using DB2 anyway, you should prefer manipulation DATE/DATETIME/TIMESTAMP values with SQL inside the query.
   I'm using Oracle and I don't know the functions for conversions and for calculations with these types in DB2, but I am absolutely sure that they exist, so you should know them and use them. Handling dates in SQL is much easier than handling them in Javascript.
2. Avoid manipulating `queryText` if possible. Use bind variables instead.

Consider using a query like

```
WITH
params_raw AS (
    SELECT ? as from_date,
           ? as to_date
      FROM DUAL -- DUAL is Oracle-specific, but there is something similar in DB2: A table that always contains exactly one row.
),
params_cooked AS (
    SELECT from_date             AS from_date_incl,
           to_date + 1 / (24*60) AS to_date_excl -- Oracle-specific date arithmethic
      FROM params_raw 
)
SELECT ...
  FROM params, some_table, ...
 WHERE some_table.some_date_column >= params.from_date_incl
   AND some_table.some_date_coulmn <  params.to_date_excl
   AND ... other conditions ...
ORDER BY ...
```

3. By convention, variables should start with a lowercase letter.
4. Be aware of implicit type conversions. These are causing enough headache in statically typed languages, but they are really dangerous in languages like Javascript.

Comment: You only mentioned what NOT to do.  What is the way to do it correctly?  I don't see where I am converting anything.  The date is formatted as "Mon Jan 01 00:01:00 EST 2024" before the last line because I have already checked that by alerting it to the screen when testing.  Seems like BIRT is doing something by default.

Comment: You *cannot* check that by simple alerting it to the screen, because in order to show the the same implicit type conversion occurs.